# Tools to measure the nonrandomness of databases

Tags: mathematical-statistics, randomness

I was working on historical data looking for anomalous patterns that we would not expect to occur at random. I'd like to create a scheme to analyze data and markets to test for statistical significance and consistency over time.

**Question :** Are there some tools we could use to evaluate the nonrandomness of a database? What do we use usually to say that something is random or not (statistically)? Figure we work with change in some value over time.

**Question :** Does the Benford's law could answer in part this question?